# What could cause a dependency not to be set in Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, required

I came across Spring's `@Required` annotation and I am not sure when to use it.

My main interrogation is: **What could cause a Spring dependency not to be set thereby justifying the use of `@Required`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check out [*4.9.1 @Required*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-required-annotation) in reference documentation. IMHO The usage of this annotation is limited these days when autowiring is so commonly used.

It was quite nice in the XML days - if you forgot to define `<property name="movieFinder" .../>` in XML but remembered to put `@Required` around `movieFinder` field or setter, Spring would throw an exception.

Note that this annotation won't save you from the most common Spring-novice error - creating a bean manually using `new` operator, outside of container control. Spring has to post-process the bean and throws exception only when the annotated class was actually created by the container (but the dependency was not injexted).

These days you just annotate that field with `@Autowired`/`@Resource`/`@Inject` and if bean is not found (otherwise leaving `null`) exception is thrown (*no such bean* or similar). If you can put `@Required` annotation, what is preventing you from replacing it with `@Autowired` and getting rid of XML altogether?

That being said, for some `@Required` might have a nice documentation value.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation. Just wondering is it a likely scenario where you are using XML to define bean (instead of simple annotation) and using annotation like `@Required` ? If you are using annotation to define bean then how `@Required` will come to rescue?

Comment: @Ajinkya: once again IMHO if you already started using annotations, go for them completely. As I wrote above if you are using annotations, by default they already throw an exception if bean is not found. So `@Required` is kind of redundant.

Comment: Then how would you configure an object from an external library using only annotations?

Comment: @smp7d: using Spring Java `@Configuration` - available from Spring 3.0/3.1. XML is no longer needed, almost completely.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "using only annotations", not "without using xml". Conceptually, is there any Spring dependency resolution advantage in your opinion to using @Configuration vs using xml in the simple case I mentioned? Do you just think it is prudent to prevent mixing of configuration styles?

Comment: @smp7d: there is nothing wrong with XML, if you like it. But if you decided to put Spring-specific `@Required` annotation in your code, why not replace it with equivalent `@Autowired` and get rid of `<property/>`? So you only have empty `<bean/>` declarations in XML. Why not get rid of them and use `@Service`?

Answer (score 1):

It is to prevent developer error for the most part.

Sometimes developers think that something will be on the context that is not actually there for a plethora of reasons, including:

1. Simply forgot to add the bean
2. Dependency issue (when components from dependencies are autodetected)
3. Type/Package misunderstanding

In these cases it is nicer to fail on context load instead of something like an NPE later.